# How to make css available for gmail using sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail, sendgrid, sendgrid-ruby

I am using Sendgrid api for my rails application to send email but in gmail is not supporting the css written within head tag what should I do to make css working.

Comment: did you try inline style

Comment: I can not add because css is very complex and how can I add css to each tag.

Comment: set css files path with server url if you project is deployed somewhere like : `http://project.herokuapp.com/assets/style.css` otherwise you will have to go for inline styles

Comment: is there any option available just like mandrill to allow css like in mandrell we have inline_css option.

Comment: You can check out this gem premailer-rails which may offer what you need to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, this is unrelated to your use of SendGrid.

According to FreshInbox, Gmail is unique amongst the major web mail clients in that it is completely incompatible with normal selectors within style tags within the head. This is due to the fact that it changes all of the classes and ids in your emails. You can get around this by using [non-standard selectors](http://freshinbox.com/blog/gmail-supports-style-sort-of/).

Typically though, developers work around this by using in-line styles. As bwest mentioned, the [premailer-rails gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/premailer-rails/versions/1.9.0) can help you accomplish this by automatically including your styles from a stylesheet as in-line. It's very simple to use, just add nokogiri and premailer-rails to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'premailer-rails'
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure compatibility with the greatest number of email clients, you should use inline css whenever you send HTML emails. Currently we don't offer this as part of SendGrid, but you can use a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/premailer-rails/versions/1.9.0) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Gemfile.rb

```
gem 'roadie-rails'
```

than inside of x_mailer.rb

```
include Roadie::Rails::Automatic
```